# What are some good tools, if any, for Gtk3 / Gnome Shell theme/extension development?

Tags: javascript, css, gtk3

I am a seasoned web developer (XHTML/CSS/JavaScript/X-Browser), and have just installed Fedora 15. Fedora is on the bleeding edge, and ships with Gnome 3 / Gnome Shell as the default desktop. I know Gnome3, Gtk3, Mutter, and Gnome Shell use web technologies for their theming and extensions. Is there a good editor/IDE for developing and testing these themes/extensions? I am currently working on a suite of Rubles in Eclipse/Aptana for this purpose, but I would like to save some time if anyone knows any better tools.

Answer (score 4):

Gtk3 uses a web alike technology that looks like CSS but is not.

And no, at the moment Gtk3 does not have any tools and not even an  documentation for it's theming layer.

It's all done trial and error by cloning another theme and playing with it.